# How to make a menu invisible for users coming under perticular group in openerp 7?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I want to make a menu invisible for users belonging to particular group. For example, I have created a new settings menu which is for users coming under the group 'admin_limited'. These users should not get the default settings menu, Now view of the settings menu is managed by administration's 'access right' or 'settings' group.

Answer (score 1):

You have to apply a groups on menu to whome you want to give a rights to view perticular menu, that group determine access rights to different resource, if user belongs to several group will able to access.
You can apply group on menu like:

```
 <menuitem id="xxx" action="xxx" parent="xxx" groups="base.group_no_one"/>
```

Comment: Some of the users come under base.group_no_one group. So I cant use this too.

Comment: You have to create your own group and them access rights you want.